# Vue.js Javascript remove from list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a `votes` array with users. Now I would like to remove a user 
based on his id.

```
role: 2
active: 2
about: null
id: 3
email: "test@gmail.com.com"
created_at: "2016-11-08 17:14:16"
function: "functie...."
last_name: "Janssen"
mobile: "6"
pivot: Object
updated_at: "2016-11-08 17:30:20"
```

Method:

```
option.votes.$remove($root.user.id);
```

Obviously this is not working. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Are you using vue 2.0? `$remove` has been deprecated in 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
newArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.id !== 'idToDelete';
});
option.votes = newArray
```